# Bash: Formatting date

Tags: bash, date, git-bash

I would like to use date in the following format: `yyyyMM.dd.HHmm`.  i.e. `202008.15.1742`

This is the Bash file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
VERSION_CODE=$((($(date +%s%N)/1000000))
plutil -replace CFBundleVersion -string "$VERSION_CODE"
```

How do I set `VERSION_CODE` such that the current time appears in this format: `yyyyMM.dd.HHmm`?

Comment: #VERSION_CODE=$(date +%Y%m.%d.%H%M)
#echo $VERSION_CODE
202008.13.2155

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
VERSION_CODE=$(date +"%Y%m.%d.%H%M")
```

Answer (score 5):

A pure Bash solution without spawning a sub-process:

```sh
printf -v VERSION_CODE '%(%Y%m.%d.%H%M)T'
```